# How to display array value in HTML

Tags: html, angular, angular8

Cannot output "latitude" and "longitude" in html. I tried to do it through forEach, but it fails [image]

```
this.otherService.getList().subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      this.atm = response;
```

HTML

```
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of atm">
      <p class="listTitle">{{item.latitude}}</p>
      <p class="listSubTitle">{{item.longitude}}</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to assign `this.atm = response.terminals;`

Answer (score 0):

use-

```
this.otherService.getList().subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      this.atm = response.terminals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do,

```
this.atm = response.terminals;
```

The above will assign the array of objects to the atm, so that you can use ngFor to iterate over them

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update your .ts file code below then it will work fine.

```
this.otherService.getList().subscribe(
    (response: any) => {
      this.atm = response.terminals;
```

Or else can you please update the HTML code

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let item of atm.terminals">
      <p class="listTitle">{{item.latitude}}</p>
      <p class="listSubTitle">{{item.longitude}}</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are logically right and the procedure you followed to print the array is also right but you are iterating over an response object instead of **terminals** array.

So, if you only need **terminals** array from response then,

DO THE FOLLOWING,

```
this.otherService.getList().subscribe(
(response: any) => {
  this.atm = response.terminals;}
```

And, if you need other keys from response object also, then

DO THE FOLLOWING,

```
this.otherService.getList().subscribe(
(response: any) => {
  this.atm = response;}
```

and somewhere in your code,you can do like,

```
let terminals: [] = atm.terminals;
```

and you can use **terminals** wherever you want in your code.